# How can I get the HTML element from an animationend?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
document.addEventListener('animationend', (evnt: AnimationEvent) => {
})
```

I am trying to get the element that just had the animation end. I can't figure out which property on `evnt` to use. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The animationend event is fired when a CSS Animation has completed. So the best way is to get the element before and add the event listener on that element. If you want to catch any animation check out the properties of the event object `console.log(event)` in the called function (I think currentTarget has your value)

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: Can you post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animationend event is fired when a CSS Animation has completed.

So the best way is to get the element before and add the event listener on that element.

If you want to catch any animation check out the properties of the event object

`console.log(event)` in the called function (I think currentTarget has your value)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement